# Asus laptop makes weird sound when touched

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio, speakers, asus-laptop

I've had my Asus N56VV-S4021H for about 1 year and a half.  It runs Windows 8.1.

Recently, it started making a sound every time I touch it.  Whenever I type, knock on the laptop's case, touch the screen, etc., the speaker makes a corresponding echo. When I turn the volume down, the echo is weaker and when I turn off the volume completely, I can't hear it at all. I don't know what happened.

Can anyone help me get rid of these bizarre sounds?

Comment: Since the laptop casing is metal it might be a grounding issue. Does it happen when running on battery? Have you tried a different power outlet?

Comment: I've removed the battery then plugged it in again but still, the problem remains. The same result happened when I tried with another outlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like the microphone is recording for some reason.  Can you hear your own voice echoing when you speak?

Try disabling the microphone in your Sound control panel.  Go to the Recording tab and click the Properties button.  Then under Device Usage, select "Don't use this device (disable) and hit OK.  Do this for each audio input device and see if it resolves your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it. Here's what you'll need to do:

1. Go to Control Panel and click Hardware and Sound.
2. Under Sound, click Manage Audio Devices.
3. Go to Recording tab and right click on microphone and choose properties.
4. Go to Listen tab and uncheck the box for "Listen to this device".

You're all set!